# Default values for an Angular.js directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is that I need to create a directive that takes it's elements from controllers scope or if its not defined in scope take it from DOM elements.
This is my directive:

```
rmsUtils.directive('rmsDateRange', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var date = {
                'start' : element.find('[rms-date-range-field=start]').val(),
                'end' : element.find('[rms-date-range-field=end]').val(),
            };
            element.datepicker({
                format: "yyyy",
                startView: 1,
                minViewMode: 2,
                autoclose: true
            }).on('changeDate', function(e){
                var year = e.date.getFullYear(),
                id = e.target.getAttribute('rms-date-range-field');
                date[id] = String(year);
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            function read() {
                controller.$setViewValue(date);
            }

            read();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Element looks like:

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange input-group-sm" rms-date-range id="id_birth_date_range" name="birth_date_range" ng-model="filters.birth_date_range" ng-show="showCustomBirthYears()">
    <input class="form-control input-xs" type="text" rms-date-range-field="start" value="1980">
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input class="form-control input-xs" type="text" rms-date-range-field="end" value="1995">
</div>
```

And the controller is let's say a simple ctrl that defines `$scope.filters.birth_date_range = {start: 2000, end: 2010}`.

The values are assigned correctly but when my directive gets initialized it's reassigning them to 1980, 1995. In the `link()` of my directive before calling the `read()` function `controller.$viewValue` and `controller.$modelValue` are `undefined`.

Any help is very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being reset because in your link function you are setting the date variable to values taken from start and end input elements. Then in your read function you update the view value which in turn updates the model value which is your scope variable.
SO, once when the link function calls read, the scope variable is updated to what is in the text box.

I could help more specificly If you could further explain what are you trying to do.

HTH

Comment: Yea thanks I knew what is happening here. I want to check if a variable in scope passed as ng-model to my directive is already set or undefined.